# concatenate in django template

Tags: python, django, templates

Why does in this snippet `id="{{field_index}}"` is empty, it doesn't print me "field_version_" or "field_controparte" depending of key?

```
 <form id="formDoc" style="margin-top: 10px;" action="/" method="post">
        {% for keyFi,valueFi in tmplVar.jsonKeysDocFields.items %}
            
        {% with field_index="field_"|add:keyFi|stringformat:"s" %}
    
            <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: none;" id="{{field_index}}" class="docFieldWrapper"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#add) of the `add` template filter:

> This filter will first try to coerce both values to integers. If this
> fails, it’ll attempt to add the values together anyway. This will work
> on some data types (strings, list, etc.) and fail on others. If it
> fails, the result will be an empty string.

I am guessing that your `keyFi` variable is `None` or some other type. Try debugging and checking for what value does that variable take.

Comment: Yes because `add` want same type. I can't add a str to int, it return an empty string because it raise in error.

Comment: I think the best way to go is the custom filter you put in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried also build a custom tag

file pyconcat_tags.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.filter
def concat_string(value_1, value_2):
    return str(value_1) + str(value_2)
```

file home.html

```
{% load pyconcat_tags %}
    <form id="formDoc" style="margin-top: 10px;" action="process2_module_doc.php" method="post">
        {% for keyFi,valueFi in tmplVar.jsonKeysDocFields.items %}
            
        {% with field_index="field_"|concat_string:keyFi %}
        <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; display: none;" id="{{field_index}}" class="docFieldWrapper">
```

Output me field_0, field_1 depending keyFi={"0":"*version*","1":"controparte"}

It works.